# PLS-00049 : Eroor when using :NEW

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have two tables

```
A(#ref_medic,libelle, vignette,remarque, qtestock)
B(#ref_medic, #dateF, qte_lot, unite, remarque)
```

I want to use the instead of insert trigger in order to insert a row in B in case the row having its `ref_medic` is existent in A but not in B.

I keep getting the error :

> PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.REF_MEDIC'

whenever I'm inserting in this view :

This is the view I'm inserting through thanks to `INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER`

```
CREATE VIEW myview(reference,libelle,vignette, date_peremption, Quantite,unite,
    Remarque) AS
    SELECT M.ref_medic, libelle, vignette, dateF,Qte_lot,unite,LM.remarque
    FROM Medicament M, Lot_medicament LM
    WHERE M.ref_medic=LM.ref_medic
    AND qte_lot>0;
```

I tried removing `:NEW` but that's not what i'm looking forward to do as I want to insert this row in B :

```
INSERT INTO myview VALUES
('12AS45','test','yes','06/06/2021',30,'boite','test');
```

> PLS-00049: variable attachée (bind variable) erronée 'NEW.REF_MEDIC'

We should get the folllowing result: the row won't be inserted in B as it's existant there

Comment: Could you please show us the contents of `INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER`? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55622919/edit) your question and add that in order to help you.

Comment: The mistake is writing :NEW.ref_med instead of :NEW.reference inside the trigger.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a '#' in the name of your column ? it might cause problem.

Otherwise it should be working.

Here is a tested example :

```
create table Medicament(
ref_medic VARCHAR2(10),
libelle VARCHAR2(30),
vignette VARCHAR2(3),
remarque VARCHAR2(50),
qtestock NUMBER);

create table Lot_medicament(
ref_medic VARCHAR2(10),
dateF DATE,
qte_lot NUMBER,
unite VARCHAR2(15),
remarque VARCHAR2(50));

CREATE VIEW myview(reference,libelle,vignette, date_peremption, Quantite,unite, Remarque) AS
  SELECT M.ref_medic, libelle, vignette, dateF, Qte_lot, unite, LM.remarque
  FROM Medicament M, Lot_medicament LM
  WHERE M.ref_medic = LM.ref_medic
  AND qte_lot > 0;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER instead_insert_in_myview
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON myview
DECLARE
  med_ref  Medicament.ref_medic%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT ref_medic into med_ref FROM Medicament where ref_medic = :new.reference;
  EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     med_ref := NULL;
  END;
  IF med_ref IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO Medicament(ref_medic, libelle, vignette, remarque, qtestock)
     VALUES (:new.reference, :new.libelle, :new.vignette, :new.remarque, :new.Quantite);
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO Lot_medicament(ref_medic, dateF, qte_lot, unite, remarque)
   VALUES (:new.reference, :new.date_peremption, :new.Quantite, :new.unite, :new.remarque);
END instead_insert_in_myview;
/

INSERT INTO myview VALUES
('12AS45','test','yes','06/06/2021',30,'boite','test');
```

then

```
select count(*) from Medicament;
```

gives you one row, and

```
select count(*) from Lot_medicament;
```

also gives you one row.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is writing **:NEW.ref_med** *instead of* **:NEW.reference** inside the trigger.

Thanks everybody .